# Serve a different index page based on a cookie

Tags: nginx

I am setting a cookie for the user's language, something like "lang=en". I would like to rewrite a root or index.htm request to a localized index.htm file. This way if a user makes a request to "/" or "/index.htm", if he has the "lang=en" cookie set, it would rewrite the request to return the "index_en.htm" file. I would also like to have a fallback, so if the cookie isn't set, I could specify a default localized page and return it. How can I do this?

Here is my current NGINX location (site_root is an ansible var):

```
    location / {
        root {{ site_root }};
        #index  /;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /;     
    }
```

Edit:

The solution needs to be a rewrite, not a redirect as I want the user to still see "example.com/index.htm" or "example.com", not "example.com/index_en.htm". A rewrite will also prevent additional requests.

Also, I would like to use the value of the cookie like so "index_{LANG_VALUE}.htm" to make it dynamic, as the goal is to not have to edit this config file if I have to add new languages.

Edit 2:

Here is a working solution, there might be better alternatives, but this fulfills my requirements.

```
    location / {
        root {{ site_root }};

        try_files $uri
                  /index_$cookie_lang.html   #localized index if user cookie "lang" is set
                  /index_en.html             #default localized index
                  /index.html                #default index
                  =404;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
location ~ ^/$ {

    // for dynamic rewrite
    if ($http_cookie ~* "lang" ) {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index_$cookie_lang.html;
    }

    // for fixed redirects..
    if ($http_cookie ~* "lang=en") {
        return         302 https://example.com/index_en.html;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~* "lang=fr") {
        return         302 https://example.com/index_fr.html;
    }
    ..
}
```

Comment: I tried your dynamic solution and I get a 404 with the correct index_LANG.html present